# How to change data in a cloned table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a table in which users can add some text to a table, I have cloned a table using useRef.

**Live demo**: [live deom](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bush-3x9wy?file=/src/App.js:596-626)

**Expectation:**

I want if the user entered new texts in a table I want the cloned table to have predefined text instead of entered by a user but the original table should have the newly entered text by the user

[image]

Here is what I have tried

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const tableRef = useRef(null);
  const clonedTableRef = useRef(null);
  const [disclaimer, setDisclaimer] = useState();
  const [signoff, setSignOff] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    handleCopyTable();
  }, [disclaimer, signoff]);

  const handleCopyTable = () => {
    clonedTableRef.current.innerHTML = tableRef.current.innerHTML;
  };

  if (disclaimer) {
    console.log("ggggg", disclaimer);
    clonedTableRef.current.querySelector("#disclaimer").innerText =
      "Predifined Text for disclaimer";
  }

  if (signoff) {
    console.log("ggggg", signoff);
    clonedTableRef.current.querySelector("#signoff").innerText =
      "Predifined Text for signoff";
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="disclaimer-box">
        <textarea
          placeholder="Type your characters here"
          onChange={(e) => setDisclaimer(e.target.value)}
          rows="3"
          cols="30"
        ></textarea>
        <button>Add Disclaimer</button>
      </div>
      <div className="signoff-box">
        <textarea
          placeholder="Type your characters here"
          onChange={(e) => setSignOff(e.target.value)}
          rows="3"
          cols="30"
        ></textarea>
        <button>Add signoff</button>
      </div>

      <h1>Original table </h1>
      <div ref={tableRef} className="table">
        <table width="500" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" border="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr
              style={{
                fontSize: "8px",
                fontFamily: "Verdana",
                color: "#fff",
                lineHeight: "10px",
                paddingTop: "10px",
                backgroundColor: "red"
              }}
            >
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
              <td id="disclaimer" style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
                Disclaimer : {disclaimer}{" "}
              </td>
              <td id="signoff" style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
                signoff : {signoff}{" "}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <h1>Cloned Table</h1>
      <div ref={clonedTableRef} className="table"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Problem: When a user enters new text in a table the cloned table shows the new text instead of predefined text, any suggestion on what is wrong here?**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 const [disclaimer, setDisclaimer] = useState(
    "Predifined Text for disclaimer"
  );
  const [signoff, setSignOff] = useState("Predifined Text for signoff");

  useEffect(() => {
    handleCopyTable();
  }, []);

  const handleCopyTable = () => {
    clonedTableRef.current.innerHTML = tableRef.current.innerHTML;
  };
```

Remove

```
  if (disclaimer) {
    console.log("ggggg", disclaimer);
    clonedTableRef.current.querySelector("#disclaimer").innerText =
      "Predifined Text for disclaimer";
  }

  if (signoff) {
    console.log("ggggg", signoff);
    clonedTableRef.current.querySelector("#signoff").innerText =
      "Predifined Text for signoff";
  }
```

empty dependency array will copy the HTML only once when mounting

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-benji-z3rqt?file=/src/App.js:283-652

Comment: @The Dead Man, check this out!!

Comment: hej but u add those predifined only when user type somethig in textarea eg if user type something in textarea  for disclaimer it should show predefined text otherwise the original text from original table

Comment: @The Dead Man, updated the answer considering that case as well. does this solve your problem?